# Pandas: Split dataframe with duplicate values into dataframe with unique values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, on-duplicate-key

I have a dataframe in Pandas with duplicate values in Col1:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| a |
| a |
| b |
| a |
| a |
| b |

What I want to do is to split this df into different df-s with unique Col1 values in each.

DF1:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| a |
| b |

DF2:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| a |
| b |

DF3:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| a |

DF4:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| a |

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this in a vectorial way.

One possibility is to use a custom function to iterate the items and keep track of the unique ones. Then use this to split with `groupby`:

```
def cum_uniq(s):
    i = 0
    seen = set()
    out = []
    for x in s:
        if x in seen:
            i+=1
            seen = set()
        out.append(i)
        seen.add(x)
    return pd.Series(out, index=s.index)

out = [g for _,g in df.groupby(cum_uniq(df['Col1']))]
```

output:

```
[  Col1
 0    a,
   Col1
 1    a
 2    b,
   Col1
 3    a,
   Col1
 4    a
 5    b]
```

intermediate:

```
cum_uniq(df['Col1'])

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
dtype: int64
```

###### if order doesn't matter

Let's ad a Col2 to the example:

```
  Col1  Col2
0    a     0
1    a     1
2    b     2
3    a     3
4    a     4
5    b     5
```

the previous code gives:

```
[  Col1  Col2
 0    a     0,
   Col1  Col2
 1    a     1
 2    b     2,
   Col1  Col2
 3    a     3,
   Col1  Col2
 4    a     4
 5    b     5]
```

If order does not matter, you can vectorize it:

```
out = [g for _,g in df.groupby(df.groupby('Col1').cumcount())]
```

output:

```
[  Col1  Col2
0    a     0
2    b     2,
   Col1  Col2
1    a     1
5    b     5,
   Col1  Col2
3    a     3,
   Col1  Col2
4    a     4]
```